# To get Fancybox beforeShow '.fancybox-inner' size?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Is there a way to get the image `width` and `height` at `beforeShow` of fancybox somehow, to be able to run an *ajax* request before showing according to the image size? If anybody did anything like this before, would help a lot, I guess the `fancybox-inner` *class* already knows the `width` at least of the picture that is going to be shown, even when `autofit` and `autosize` are enabled, since it computes from the active browser size.

Any suggestions pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get dimensions of a fancybox image, then `.fancybox-image` is the *selector* you are looking for. You could do something like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            console.log($(".fancybox-image").width()); 
            console.log($(".fancybox-image").height());
            if ($(".fancybox-image").width() == 612) {
                // do something of width matches the value
                console.log("oh yeah, the width is 612");
            }
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/10r0Lkxc/1/)**